# Do XSLT processors validate input and output XML files if XSD is present?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Imagine I have some XSLT transformation. It transforms one XML to another. Both input and output have valid XML Schemas. Will the XSLT processor validate input and output and what will happen if it fails?

Comment: *Which* XSLT transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enforce input and/or output validation with XSLT you need to use a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor like Saxon 9 EE.

Comment: Martin, do I need some settings, or it is a default behavior?

Comment: You need to write a schema-aware transformation and you need to instruct the processor to do validation, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/html/schema-processing/satransformcmd.html for details on Saxon 9.5 EE for instance and http://www.stylusstudio.com/schema_aware.html for a tutorial like introduction (it is a bit old ,probably mentioning Saxon SA (for schema-aware) while these days Saxon EE is the version of Saxon providing schema-aware XSLT but I think it is a good introduction on the advantages and approach to write schema-aware transformations).

Answer (score 2):

> Do XSLT processors validate input and output XML files if XSD is present?

In general: No.

It would be a potentially value adding feature, but there is certainly no mandate<sup>1</sup> that it should be part of the XSLT's processors functionality.

---

<sup>1</sup> Eg. in the underlying standards: http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_XSLT